# Assuming I can't alter page css with Chrome console, can I log and style page content?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to alter styles on a webpage directly from the DevTools console (not using inspect-element methods). Specifically, I would like to know what command(s) would allow me to override the `font-family` attribute of a given `Id` (or `class`).

My searches here and elsewhere seem to indicate that I can only alter the css of console outputs. If this is an accurate statement of the limitation, my backup solution would be to pull page content into the console by class and style it there—unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Why aren't you using (or have access to) the Chrome inspector? If jQuery is loaded/available, in the console you could select the class/ID, then use .css to change the font family `$(selector).css('font-family', 'your choice');`

Comment: Can you please post some code or sample demonstrating the issue you are having?

Comment: @dward Thanks, and see my comment on Dominic's answer for more explanation if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure why you wouldn't just use the inspect element but you could do something like this with js in the console.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].style.fontFamily="Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I was missing `[0]`. I was looking to avoid inspect element in order to have something I could share with people (who could paste this into the console) rather than walking them through admittedly more sensible methods of finding and altering the appropriate style tags with Chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually alter css classes by inserting a new style element in your document.
You can do it, from your console, just using javascript, like this:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML='.adzerk-vote {color:red; background-color:blue;}';
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Just change the class you want before adding it to the document head.

If you select an element and change its classe css properties, it will take effect in all your page.

Comment: This seems like it would have a lot of good applications, thank you.